# Calling functions in Linq To SQl .net 3.5

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5

guys
How can i achieve the following

```
var productslist=from p in productsTable
                 select new product{Id=p.Id,Tax=myfunctions.calculateTax(p.price)};
```

i have tried to google and came across this [document](http://www.scribd.com/doc/37706678/Linq-Expand). Is there another way i can do this without using third party dlls

Solution: Move application to .net 4.0 (this is actually support and supposed to work). Nway i stuck to the below solution for the time being

Comment: Is `calculateTax` a stored procedure/function in your DB?

Comment: no .its a function in my code

Comment: Check the link above "document" link. its has a dll that allows u to use .ToExpandable() in your Linq queries

Comment: @lafama - that refers to processing of `Expression<...>` types; your `calculateTax` method is not an `Expression` AFAIK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you trying to call a *local* function, or one in the database? If it's a local function and it's the last thing you're doing, it's easy - you just need a call to `AsEnumerable()` to force the remainder of the query to execute locally:

```
var products = productsTable.AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(p => new Product
                                    { p.Id, Tax = CalculateTax(p.Price) });
```

Comment: Its a local functions. Please explain what u mean be the "emainder of the query to execute locally". i thought it was possible for the whole query to execute on the db

Comment: @lafama: Not if you're trying to execute local code, no. Basically my version above will pull data down from the database and call `CalculateTax` on each returned piece of data. If you want the tax calculation to execute in the database, you should write a stored procedure or UDF.

Comment: My only note is that this might fetch unnecessary columns - but since we are already lacking a `where`, that seems picky ;p

Answer (score 11):

LINQ to SQL can't magically translate *arbitrary* C# to TSQL; a *limited selection* of commonly needed syntax is available inside LINQ, but a C# method is not going to work.

Options:

- rewrite the function as a UDF (in TSQL) and map the UDF to your data-context (i.e. drag the UDF onto the designer surface); use `myDataContext.MyUdf(args)` in LINQ
- apply your function only once the data is back in .NET-land
- re-write the function as a LINQ-projection

I expect the middle option is the easiest in your scenario. For example:

```
var productslist=
            (from p in productsTable
             select new {Id=p.Id,p.price}).AsEnumerable()
            .Select(p => new {p.Id, Tax=myfunctions.calculateTax(p.price)});
```

The `AsEnumerable()` breaks "composition" - i.e. it stops LINQ-to-SQL from trying to understand `calculateTax` in terms of TSQL; only the `Id` and `price` are retrieved from SQL; then *as it processes each row* it applies the second projection to calculate the tax.